# When does aiNodeAnim animate a mesh directly and not a bone

Tags: animation, assimp

An aiNode has a field called mMeshes which is described by the documentation as "the meshes of this node". Will a node always have a mesh? If not, then what does it mean for a node to not have any meshes, could an aiNodeAnim struct exist for the node anyway? If a node has more than one mesh do the animations affect every mesh of the node?

Also there are two structures in an Animation struct the aiNodeAnim and aiMeshAnim so if aiNodeAnim describes the animation of a Node and that node has a mesh does that animate the mesh? Why would aiMeshAnim be necessary if aiNodeAnim describes the animation of a node and a node can have any number of meshes?

If I want to implement skeletal animation I'd need to support both the aiNodeAnim and aiMeshAnim channels correct?